# change color of nodes by click on

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How can I change the colour of my node? If I click on a node that was previously blue, it should change colour, e.g. to purple. But if I now click on another node, this node should become purple and the previously clicked node should get an old colour (i.e. become blue again). how do I do this?

```
const color = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 1]).range(["#03fc90", "#03dbfc"]);
var node = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "nodes")
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(dataset.nodes)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 5)
  .style("fill", function(d,i) {
    return color(i);})
   .on("click", (evt, currentNode) => {    
    d3.select(this).
    .style.color=’purple’
  });
```

Comment: With the method I created, the node could not change its colour. But I just got it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. On initial render, set default `fill` style for every node.
2. On click, find previously selected node, remove 'selected' class and set default color
3. For the new node, set 'selected' class and color

```js
const nodes = [
  {id: 1, x: 50, y: 50},
  {id: 2, x: 50, y: 100},
  {id: 3, x: 100, y: 75},
];

const svg = d3.select('svg');
  svg.selectAll('circle.node')
    .data(nodes, d => d.id)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .classed('node', true)
    .attr('cx', d => d.x)
    .attr('cy', d => d.y)
    .attr('r', 20)
    .style('fill', 'blue')
    .style('cursor', 'pointer')
    .on('click', onClickNode);
  
function onClickNode (e, d) {
  svg.selectAll('.node.selected')
    .classed('selected', false)
    .style('fill', 'blue');
  
  d3.select(this)
    .classed('selected', true)
    .style('fill', 'purple');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<svg />
```